EF Core 8 Count over Many-to-Many Relationship Generating Bad Query
I am using SQL Server 2019 and EF Core 8.
I have two entities, TenantOrganization (Organization) and SharedIndustry (Industry), that have a many-to-many relationship via a joining entity TenantOrganizationIndustries (OrganizationIndustries). Starting with the Id of an Industry, I'd like to count the number of OrganizationIndustries its related to so I can allow or deny deletion of the Industry. Shared and Tenant are schemas in the database.
The problem that I'm running into is that EF Core is generating a bad query and is misnaming a table in the join in the query. Specifically it's naming the [Tenant].[Organizations] as [TenantOrganization], where its ignoring the schema portion of the name, and is singularizing the table's name.
This is the query being generated:
SELECT TOP(1) (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Tenant].[OrganizationIndustries] AS [o]
    INNER JOIN [TenantOrganization] AS [t] ON [o].[OrganizationId] = [t].[Id]-- WRONG table name
    WHERE [i].[Id] = [o].[IndustryId])
FROM [Shared].[Industries] AS [i]
WHERE [i].[Id] = @__command_Id_0

Where the correct version of the query would be this (reformatted to my taste):
SELECT TOP(1)   (
                    SELECT  COUNT(*)
                    FROM    [Tenant].[OrganizationIndustries] AS [TOI]
                            INNER JOIN [Tenant].[Organizations] AS [TO] ON ([TOI].[OrganizationId] = [TO].[Id])-- CORRECT table name
                    WHERE   ([SI].[Id] = [TOI].[IndustryId])
                )
FROM            [Shared].[Industries] AS [SI]
WHERE           ([SI].[Id] = @__command_Id_0);

This is the LINQ query that I'm using that's creating the generated query:
_shared.Industries.Where(i => i.Id == command.Id).Select(i => i.Organizations.Count).FirstAsync(cancellationToken)

This is the navigation configuration for the entities in the DbContext:
builder.Entity<TenantOrganization>().HasMany(
    to => to.Industries).WithMany(
    si => si.Organizations).UsingEntity(
        "OrganizationIndustries",
        l => l.HasOne(typeof(SharedIndustry)).WithMany().HasForeignKey(nameof(TenantOrganizationIndustry.IndustryId)).HasPrincipalKey(nameof(SharedIndustry.Id)),
        r => r.HasOne(typeof(TenantOrganization)).WithMany().HasForeignKey(nameof(TenantOrganizationIndustry.OrganizationId)).HasPrincipalKey(nameof(TenantOrganization.Id)),
        j => j.ToTable("OrganizationIndustries", "Tenant"));

And finally these is the EF Core models:
public sealed class SharedIndustry {
    public SharedIndustryId Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TenantOrganization> Organizations { get; } = [];
}

public sealed class TenantOrganization {
    public TenantOrganizationId Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<SharedIndustry> Industries { get; } = [];
}

public sealed class TenantOrganizationIndustry {
    public SharedIndustryId IndustryId { get; set; }
    public TenantOrganizationId OrganizationId { get; set; }
}

How can I get EF Core to generate the correct query, specifically to use the correct name for the table? I'm doing this without a DbSet for TenantOrganizationIndustry, but I'm starting to wonder if I'll have to, to make it work.
Realistically the most optimal query that should be getting generated would be:
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    [Tenant].[OrganizationIndustries]
WHERE   ([IndustryId] = @__command_Id_0);

But I don't think I'll be able to without having a DbSet for TenantOrganizationIndustry. For the moment I'd like to see if I can make this many-to-many join be defined correctly so that the correct query is generated.
Help in getting to that would be highly appreciated!

.UsingEntity<TenantOrganizationIndustry>(...)? Which table doesn't exist?

Oups, sorry, the [TenantOrganization] in the query does not exist.

Why TenantOrganization do not exists? From configuration i see that this table is required. Have you executed migrations?

I don't use migrations. [Tenant].[Organizations] exists. Looks like when it's generating the query, it's not correctly writing the table's name to be Schema.Table. The configuration for TenantOrganization does specify the schema, but EF is not applying it in the join correctly: builder.ToTable(nameof(TenantContext.Organizations), Schemas.Tenant). Not sure how to make it do so.

I've revised the post for more clarity into what I'm trying to do, and what is happening.

There's no (visible) code that maps TenantOrganization to table [Tenant].[Organizations].

I honestly have no idea how it ended up working in the end, but I decided to use EF Core Power Tools to reverse engineer the database and see what it does for the many-to-many relationship. After getting nowhere with the GUI version in Visual Studio 2022, I ended up using the CLI version to reverse engineer the model and copied the configuration it did for the relationship.
The thing that stood out was that it applied the configuration on the Industry instead of the Organization like I did. I'm guessing this is simply because it was the first of the two objects in alphabetical order.
I tweaked it a little bit so it doesn't use a Dictionary<string, object> and instead my TenantOrganizationIndustry object. Here is the currently working version:
builder.HasMany(
    si => si.Organizations).WithMany(
    to => to.Industries).UsingEntity<TenantOrganizationIndustry>(
    nameof(TenantOrganizationIndustry),
    r => r.HasOne<TenantOrganization>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(toi => toi.OrganizationId),
    l => l.HasOne<SharedIndustry>().WithMany().HasForeignKey(toi => toi.IndustryId),
    j => {
        j.ToTable("OrganizationIndustries", Schemas.Tenant).HasKey(toi => new {
            toi.IndustryId,
            toi.OrganizationId
        });

        j.Property(
            toi => toi.IndustryId).HasConversion<SharedIndustryId.EfCoreValueConverter>();

        j.Property(
            toi => toi.OrganizationId).HasConversion<TenantOrganizationId.EfCoreValueConverter>();
    });

